# executing unix commands from scala script

Tags: scala, unix

I am not clear on best practice to execute unix commands from my scala based script.

A typical scala script is here

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$0" "$@"
!#

println("args length is ", args.length)

### want to list all files in the underlying folder
val resultSet = "ls -la"????
```

I checked a number of posts but nothing clearly outlines a working script which can execute a unix command from scala script and perform some transformations.

Comment: If you're going to write Scala scripts I strongly recommend you to check out **ammonite**. Short intro video (10 min) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wk2-ZsQU358 And the full docs - http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple script to get you started.

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala
import scala.sys.process._

// args is auto-populated
println("arg len = " + args.length)

// get listing of current files
val files: Array[String] = "ls -a".!!.split("\n")
println("5th fiile is " + files(4))

System.exit(0)
```

Study the [process package](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.sys.process.package) of the Standard Library for more on capturing process output, process exit status, pipelining, etc.

Answer (score 3):

import `scala.sys.process._` and use the `!` and `!!` to execute the linux commands

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
scala> "ls -la" !
scala> "ls -la" !!
```

You can do this in the `scala script` as well

`!` returns exit code of the command after executing

`!!` returns the output of the command after executing

> Parse the output of the `"ls -la" !!` and get the files in the current dir.